# react-native android LinkingIOS

Tags: android, linker, react-native

Error undefined is not an object(evaluating 'RCTLinkingManager,openURL')

The documentation says LinkingIOS is being deprecated. Use Linking instead. Yet there is nothing else about that and all references are to LinkingIOS

  `var {Image,   View,   Text,   ScrollView, BackAndroid,    StyleSheet,    LinkingIOS} = React; 
render: function() {
  var url = 'http://google.com';
    return (
        <View style={property.color}>
        <Image source={require('../img/glow2.png')} style={property.container}>
            <Navbar
                title="Property Info"
                subtitle=""
                style={property.toolbar}
                subtitleStyle={property.subtitle}   />

            <ScrollView style={{marginBottom: 55, backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
                <View style={property.propertyContent}>
                    <Icon name="android-checkbox-outline" size={20} color="rgba(255,255,255,0.9)" style={{position: 'absolute',top:0, left: 0}}/>
                <Text style={property.content}>url   {url} </Text>
                <Text style={{color: 'yellow'}} 
                onPress={() => LinkingIOS.openURL(url)}>
                Google</Text>

            </ScrollView>
        </Image>
        </View>
    );
}`

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: LinkingIOS is being deprecated. Use Linking instead.

This means you should be using `Linking` as a reference in your code rather than `LinkingIOS`.

Comment: Hi,
Very little info about this, just a mention in docs and switching out makes no difference.
Thanks,
John